# How Do I Edit The Keywords on an Amazon.com Search Without Affecting the Other Search Filters?

Tags: amazon

On Amazon.com, if you start a search by putting in keywords in the search bar and then proceed to add some filters using the left sidebar (e.g. prime only, 4 stars or more), there is no obvious way to modify the original keywords while leaving the other search filters intact. Typing in new keywords in the search bar start a whole new search and resets all the other filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the keywords in the breadcrumb trail to make them editable.

[image]